# Use Wireless access point in VMWare

Tags: vmware

I'm learning some WiFi security stuff, and I have installed Ubuntu in my VMWare Workstation 11 environment. My host OS is Windows 7 which is connected to my home network over Wifi

Now what I need is in the guest OS (i.e. Ubuntu), I should be able to enable Wireless access (so that I can run Wifi network scans etc). I bridged my network and laso used NAT, both of which give me access to my home network via my Host but they appear as wired connections in Ubuntu. As I understand, this is only possible by using a USB WiFi dongle.

I have purchased a USB WiFi dongle now (it should arrive in a couple of days), but I'm not sure how can I get my Ubuntu guest OS to use that USB Wifi adapter while keeping my Host OS on the built-in Wifi adapter.

Do I simple plug in the USB network adapter into my laptop and it will be recognised in Ubuntu or do I need to make some settings in VMware?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, posting my answer for posterity

I bought a TP Link WN823N USB Wifi adapter.

1) Keep your host Wifi on. Plug in the USB, let it download the drivers
2) Once installed, power on your VM
3) Open VMWare, right click on your VM -> Removable Devices
Here you should see your USB adapter. Select Connect (Disconnect from Host). This will now connect the USB Wifi adapter to your Linux VM and viola - it should just work!

Essentially what this does is the WiFi adapter will be connected to the VM and disconnected from the host, and the host can continue to use the built-in WiFi.